# how to overide css of ss-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, ng-bootstrap

I want to override the style of ss-multiselect-dropdown in angular 7 I use it by installing ngb multiselect
how do i overide css

Comment: <ss-multiselect-dropdown style="color: black; background-color:transparent;bordercolor: #d5c2c2;" [options]="myOptions" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>

Comment: Find the css rule name, and use !important on each of your styles to override.

Answer (score 0):

For most library components, you can't override directly its CSS.

I guess that Angular will make **:host ng-deep** *"deprecated"* but, until then, you can use them in order to achive the override.

For instance, in the CSS file of the HTML where you have your "<ss-multiselect-dropdown..", write something like this (change the attributes as you wish):

```
:host ::ng-deep {

  .dropdown-item {
    padding: 0.438rem 1rem;
  }
  .dropdown-item:not(.disabled).active {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .dropdown-inline {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 15rem;
    max-width: 15rem;
  }

  .btn-block {
    height: 100%;
    border-color: black;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown style="color: black; 
background-color:transparent;bordercolor: #d5c2c2;" 
[options]="myOptions" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"> 
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**CSS**

```
ss-multiselect-dropdown {
   color: blue !important;
   font-size: 160px !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```